# In gdb how to set breakpoint on any line that has a particular word?

Tags: c, gdb, breakpoints

I want that while my program is executing under gdb, 
Before executing any line of code check if the line has a particular word example a macro name or a variable name or any particular word, and if it has that then stop the execution.
Better if it can be done using regular expression.

I know there is a command `rbreak` or `rb` but that sets breakpoint on matching function name, that is not what I want.

So is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outside of gdb, you can search your source and list your breakpoints first, then call gdb with -x flag to set these breakpoints.

**plan**

> - grep over the source for user-defined patterns ( eg. erase, delete )
> - generate the break statements based on above line numbers, write these to file
> - call gdb with -x flag and point at generated file with break statements

**man gdb**

```
   ...
   -x file
       Execute GDB commands from file file.
   ...
```

---

**write_breakpoints.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sourcename="$1";
patterns="$2";
outbreaks="$3";

grep -En "$2" "$1" | \
  cut -d: -f1 | \
  sed "s/^\(.\+\)$/break $1:\1/g" 1>>"$3";
```

**example.c**

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void delete()
{
  printf("!! data is being deleted..\n");
}

void erase()
{
  printf("!! data is being erased..\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("this line is safe..\n");
  erase();
  delete();
  return 0;
}
```

**usage**

```
$ gcc -g example.c -o example
$ ./write_breakpoints.sh example.c "(delete|erase)" "breakpoints.txt"

$ gdb -x breakpoints.txt example
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from example...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400531: file example.c, line 3.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400531: file example.c, line 5.
Breakpoint 3 at 0x400541: file example.c, line 8.
Breakpoint 4 at 0x400541: file example.c, line 10.
Breakpoint 5 at 0x40055b: file example.c, line 16.
Breakpoint 6 at 0x400565: file example.c, line 17.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path/to/example 
this line is safe..

Breakpoint 5, main () at example.c:16
16    erase();
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, erase () at example.c:10
10    printf("!! data is being erased..\n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
!! data is being erased..

Breakpoint 6, main () at example.c:17
17    delete();
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, delete () at example.c:5
5     printf("!! data is being deleted..\n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
!! data is being deleted..
[Inferior 1 (process 26130) exited normally]
(gdb) quit
```

---

**notes**

- can call write_breakpoints with multiple source files ( as it appends the break statements )
- it may also be possible to do this inside gdb using [forward-search](http://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/sugon/intel/debugger/cl/commandref/gdb_mode/cmd_forward_sear.htm) and b

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible?

No.

GDB doesn't *look* at your source *at all*. It just inserts breakpoints at certain locations, and then runs the program at full speed, until one of the breakpoints is hit.

What you are asking for is for GDB to execute `next` command repeatedly, and then conditionally continue if the line you are on does not match your regexp. I am not sure it's possible to script this, but even if it is, this will be *impractically slow* for any non-trivial program.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @amdixon's answer, I wrote a one-liner that's friendly for git repos (and wouldn't be hard to modify for svn, merc, etc.)  It can be run from the repo root or any subdirectory.

```
git ls-files '*.cpp' -z | xargs -n1 -P4 -0 awk -v wd=$(pwd) '/[REGEX]/ {print "break \"" wd "/" FILENAME ":" NR "\""}' >outbreak
```

Where [REGEX] is your regex.  The file is good to run from any directory, so in my case:

```
mv outbreak /pathToExecutable
cd !$
cgdb -x outbreak executable
```

**Explanation**

`-z`, `-0`, and `\"` are all to deal with spaces/eols in the path.  `-n1` causes awk to parse one file at a time (otherwise the line numbers will be wrong because it will treat it like a giant glob).  `P4` allows awk to run 4 processes at once (for speed--optional).  `-v wd=$(pwd)` passes the working directory to awk as `wd` and `FILENAME` and `NR` are awk builtins.